# XnSensorServer CPU consumption

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I notice that XnSensorServer is consistently consuming 43% of the CPU resource.  Is there any way of reducing this, and what code is associated with it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10151/xnsensorserver-cpu-consumption/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I notice that if I set depth_registration to false within openni_camera then CPU usage drops by 30% to a much more reasonable value.  Is depth_registration just registering the RGB image with the depth image?

---

Originally posted by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) with karma: 995 on 2011-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, registration is done only for rgb point clouds. This might have changed since my last peek at the [source code](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/openni_camera/html/classopenni__camera_1_1OpenNINodelet.html)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-06-03**:
So since I'm only using the depth data - the point cloud throttling strips out the RGB values - this won't be a problem.